# Kibana failed to start

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Elasticsearch working with no issues on http://localhost:9200
And Operating system is Ubuntu 18.04

Here is the error log for Kibana

```
root@syed-MS-7B17:/var/log# journalctl -fu kibana.service
-- Logs begin at Sat 2020-01-04 18:30:58 IST. --
Apr 03 20:22:49 syed-MS-7B17 kibana[7165]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-04-03T14:52:49Z","tags":["fatal","root"],"pid":7165,"message":"{ Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 7.0.0.1:5601\n    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1263:19)\n    at listenInCluster (net.js:1328:12)\n    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen (net.js:1461:7)\n    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:61:10)\n  code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',\n  errno: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',\n  syscall: 'listen',\n  address: '7.0.0.1',\n  port: 5601 }"}
Apr 03 20:22:49 syed-MS-7B17 kibana[7165]:  FATAL  Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 7.0.0.1:5601
Apr 03 20:22:50 syed-MS-7B17 systemd[1]: kibana.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 03 20:22:50 syed-MS-7B17 systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 03 20:22:53 syed-MS-7B17 systemd[1]: kibana.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 03 20:22:53 syed-MS-7B17 systemd[1]: kibana.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Apr 03 20:22:53 syed-MS-7B17 systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
Apr 03 20:22:53 syed-MS-7B17 systemd[1]: kibana.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 03 20:22:53 syed-MS-7B17 systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 03 20:22:53 syed-MS-7B17 systemd[1]: Failed to start Kibana.
```

Comment: You might have misconfigured your kibana: can you verify that `7.0.0.1:5601` is changed to `127.0.0.1:5601` ?

Comment: I didn't do any configuration @Val

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved it myself after checking the /etc/hosts file
It was edited by mistake like below

```
7.0.0.1 localhost
```